# How does the Kafka Streams DSL process method work?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I've been working with Kafka Streams a bit and got some basic functionality working but I'm having some trouble wrapping my head around the `process` method in the Kafka Streams DSL. Specifically:

I know there are two ways of using Kafka Streams, the lower-level Processing API and the higher level Streams DSL. With the lower level you more explicitly define your topology, naming each node and such while the Streams DSL abstracts most of that away.

However, the higher level Streams DSL has a method called [`process()`](https://kafka.apache.org/20/documentation/streams/developer-guide/dsl-api.html#applying-processors-and-transformers-processor-api-integration) which is a terminal operation (i.e. the method returns `void`). So my question is, where does the processed data - the data that the `Processor`'s `void forward(key, value)` method sends - go?

In the lower level Processing API, you name you processor Node and can link `Sink`s to that name but in the Streams DSL there is no name, or at least none that I can find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible but "clumsy" to `forward()` data from a `Processor` in the DSL. As you stated, the `process()` method is defined as terminal operation and thus, you should not call `forward()`. If you call `forward()` anyway and there is no downstream processor assigned, `forward()` is basically a no-op.

However, instead of trying add a downstream processor for `process()` (what would be a hack), you should use `transform()` (and related methods, `transformValues()`, `flatTransform()`, and `flatTransformValues()`) instead ff you want to send data down stream.

Comment: I was aware of (some of) the transform methods, my confusion arose I think from the name `process` and the "Processing API" assuming that they were more intimately related than they are. Behind the scenes `Transformers` and `Processors` are pretty much the same thing. I wasn't looking at `Transformers` first because I (thought I) wanted process because I wanted to use `forward()`. I wasn't aware `flatTransform` could also be used to reduce (combine) messages, as in my mind, 'flattening' generally turns something into more messages, not fewer, which is my use case.

Comment: Is it possible to forward data to a "specific" child ( using the "to" arg) to a specific DSL process? I feel like using .forward() in a transform in the DSL only sends it to the next processor and no specific processor.

Comment: Yes, if you know the name of the downstream (child) processor. Note: you can only forward to child processors. By default, if there is more than one child processor, the record is send to all of them. If you use `To` you can pick to which child processor you send the record (instead of all). But you cannot forward a record to a non-child processor.